# Python Socket Receive/Send Multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

I am writing a Python program where in the main thread I am continuously (in a loop) receiving data through a TCP socket, using the recv function. In a callback function, I am sending data through the same socket, using the sendall function. What triggers the callback is irrelevant. I've set my socket to blocking.

My question is, is this safe to do? My understanding is that a callback function is called on a separate thread (not the main thread). Is the Python socket object thread-safe? From my research, I've been getting conflicting answers.

Comment: There are a few hidden questions in here that you're trying to solve at once. Hopefully I gave you an elaborate answer, but feel free to ask if you do not understand.

Comment: Consider using asynchronous I/O for your use case, then you won't need threads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sockets in Python are not thread safe.

You're trying to solve a few problems at once:

1. Sockets are not thread-safe.
2. recv is blocking and blocks the main thread.
3. sendall is being used from a different thread.

You may solve these by either using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or solving it the way asyncio solves it internally: By using `select.select` together with a `socketpair`, and using a queue for the incoming data.

```
import select
import socket
import queue

# Any data received by this queue will be sent
send_queue = queue.Queue()

# Any data sent to ssock shows up on rsock
rsock, ssock = socket.socketpair()

main_socket = socket.socket()

# Create the connection with main_socket, fill this up with your code

# Your callback thread
def different_thread():
    # Put the data to send inside the queue
    send_queue.put(data)

    # Trigger the main thread by sending data to ssock which goes to rsock
    ssock.send(b"\x00")

# Run the callback thread

while True:
    # When either main_socket has data or rsock has data, select.select will return
    rlist, _, _ = select.select([main_socket, rsock], [], [])
    for ready_socket in rlist:
        if ready_socket is main_socket:
            data = main_socket.recv(1024)
            # Do stuff with data, fill this up with your code
        else:
            # Ready_socket is rsock
            rsock.recv(1)  # Dump the ready mark
            # Send the data.
            main_socket.sendall(send_queue.get())
```

We use multiple constructs in here. You will have to fill up the empty spaces with your code of choice. As for the explanation:

We first create a `send_queue` which is a queue of data to send. Then, we create a pair of connected sockets (`socketpair()`). We need this later on in order to wake up the main thread as we don't wish `recv()` to block and prevent writing to the socket.

Then, we connect the `main_socket` and start the callback thread. Now here's the magic:

In the main thread, we use `select.select` to know if the `rsock` or `main_socket` has any data. If one of them has data, the main thread wakes up.

Upon adding data to the queue, we wake up the main thread by signaling `ssock` which wakes up `rsock` and thus returns from `select.select`.

In order to fully understand this, you'll have to read [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select), [`socketpair()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair) and [`queue.Queue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue).

---

@tobias.mcnulty asked a good question in the comments: Why should we use a `Queue` instead of sending all the data through the socket?

You can use the `socketpair` to send the data as well, which has its benefits, but sending over a queue might be preferable for multiple reasons:

1. Sending data over a socket is an expensive operation. It requires a syscall, requires passing data back and forth inside system buffers, and entails full use of the TCP stack. Using a `Queue` guarantees we'll have only 1 call - for the single-byte signal - and not more (apart from the queue's internal lock, but that one is pretty cheap). Sending large data through the `socketpair` will result in multiple syscalls. As a tip, you may as well use a `collections.deque` which CPython guarantees to be thread-safe because of the GIL. That way you won't have to require any syscall besides the `socketpair`.
2. Architecture-wise, using a queue allows you to have finer-grained control later on. For example, the data can be sent in whichever type you wish and be decoded afterwards. This allows the main loop to be a little smarter and can help you create an easier interface.
3. You don't have size limits. It can be a bug or a feature. I believe changing the system's buffer size is not exactly encouraged, which creates a natural throttle to the amount of data you can send. It might be a benefit, but the application may wish to control it on its own. Using the "natural" feature will cause the calling thread to hang.
4. Just like `socketpair.recv` syscalls, for large data you will pass through multiple `select` calls as well. TCP does not have message boundaries. You'll either have to create artificial ones, set the socket to nonblocking and deal with asynchronous sockets, or think of it as a stream and continuously pass through `select` calls which might be expensive depending on your OS.
5. Support for multiple threads on the same socketpair. Sending 1 byte for signalling over a socket from multiple threads is fine, and is exactly how asyncio works. Sending more than that may cause the data to be sent in an incorrect order.

All in all, transferring the data back and forth between the kernel and userspace is possible and will work, but I personally do not recommend it.

Comment: I am actually using MicroPython, and it seems like MicroPython doesn't support socket.socketpair(). Is there anyway around that? Maybe creating a similar function or just creating two additional sockets? Thanks!

Comment: @Alon `socketpair` has almost the same action as creating 2 sockets over localhost. You may either create 2 sockets, or set a low `select.select` timeout and poll. I obviously don't like the polling option as it wastes resources, slower, and if you're already running on MicroPython I guess you have a reason doing it and polling would suck. Go for two additional sockets.

Comment: @Alon Keep in mind that over unix `select.select` also works with any other file descriptor and no just sockets. You may use a different fd if it helps you in any way but I don't see the advantages doing so (pipes will be a little more efficient 
I guess but not worth breaking cross compatibility for that).

Comment: If I need to create two additional sockets (three in total), would it be better to just create two TCP socket connections, and use one for input and one for output? It would require one less socket, and might be easier to code.

Comment: `selector` module is better

Comment: @PersianGulf True and false. It doesn't matter as much. I usually suggest using selectors but in this scenario it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `Queue` to store the data on its way to the underlying socket, instead of writing it to (and reading it from) the `socketpair` directly? AFAICT, the latter would both be simpler and provide some reasonable throttling to ensure the underlying socket was keeping up with the data being sent (subject to `net.core.rmem_max`)...

Comment: @tobias.mcnulty Good question, answered above.

Comment: @Bharel Excellent response, many thanks! All points are well taken, but in particular #5. I can see how non-sensical data could easily be sent over the real socket, if multiple threads were sending data directly through the socketpair at once. And maintaining with one socketpair for each thread sounds like a pain. Thanks again for the answer + response to this question!