# Create a separate thread for every row of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe which has around 15 columns which contains values of various parameters,lets call them stock1,stock2,alpha,beta and sigma etc.

I have a function which keeps returning the data that it receives from a websocket connection(the data is ticks of various stocks).

I want to pass on these ticks to another function that I have written,that takes the data from the dataframe one row at a time(every row corresponds to a separate stock),performs some calculations with the data received from the ticks and the parameters available in the data frame.I want to run this function in multi threaded mode,where a separate thread is created for every row of the data frame.

Please suggest how can this be implemented in python.

Comment: I think this might be too broad/vague for Stack Overflow, you can find plenty of resources on the subject elsewhere. As an aside, using a thread for each row is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @tim_2020 This might be helpful please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51104534/python-socket-receive-send-multi-threading